# how to instantiate an object from an array above the previously instantiated object from the same array?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, scripting, instantiation

I have searched a lot but unable to find a solution so please help.Basically what I am trying to do is as you can see in the simplified script that I have made an array(it have three items an each is parent of its child objects) and then instantiating these items randomly.What I want is that the first instantiate should occur above an object already in the scene but then the second object should instantiate on above the previous instantiated object and the third one above the second instantiate and so on. Now what I think I want is a way to determine if instantiate(**if this is not possible then we can put instantiate in a separate function and check if that happened or no but I don't understand how to put either of these two checks in if condition**) have occurred or no,that is the condition for if statement,if it is yes then I need a reference to the last instantiation that occurred so I can put it equal to lastRedgeSet. Please help and also suggest a better way of doing this if any
`

```
 public GameObject[] RedgeSets;
 private GameObject LastRedgeSet;
 public GameObject FixedRedges;
 private Object myist;
 void Start () {
     LastRedgeSet = FixedRedges;
     }

 void Update () {
     // if(instantiate happened or no Condition here){
     //LatRedgeSet = (refrence to last instantiated object required  here) }
     Vector3 LastRedgeSetPos = LastRedgeSet.transform.position;
     Vector3 addheight = new Vector3 (0, 5, 0);
     if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Z)) {
         Instantiate (RedgeSets [UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, 3)], LastRedgeSetPos + addheight, Quaternion.identity);
     }
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get reference to the last instantiated object, the Instantiate keyworked returns the Object that was created. You can cast it to a GameObject.

It should look something like this:

```
public class Test: MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] RedgeSets;
    private GameObject lastInstanceObj;
    bool firstRun = true;

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 addheight = new Vector3(0, 5, 0);
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z))
        {
            if (firstRun)
            {
                lastInstanceObj = Instantiate(RedgeSets[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, RedgeSets.Length)], addheight, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                firstRun = false;
            }
            else
            {
                lastInstanceObj = Instantiate(RedgeSets[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, RedgeSets.Length)], lastInstanceObj.transform.position + addheight, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, you don't even need to get the reference in order to increase the y-pos of the next GameObject. You can create a value that you increment each time you press the z key.

I have no idea what `LastRedgeSet` and `FixedRedges` are but something below should do the work.

```
public GameObject[] RedgeSets;
private Object myist;

const float incrementAmount = 5;
float currentIncremenet;

void Start()
{
    currentIncremenet = incrementAmount;
}

void Update()
{
    Vector3 addheight = new Vector3(0, currentIncremenet, 0);
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z))
    {
        Instantiate(RedgeSets[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 3)], addheight, Quaternion.identity);
        currentIncremenet += incrementAmount; //Inrement the next Y axis(Increments by 5)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks alot for your solution i tried it and it works good but theres a problem...As the objects in array are of different lengths so the object are being instantiated on each other but the height do increases ...to encounter this problem i wanted to instantiate object above the previously instantiated object for that i used variable lastredgeset redgeset is actually the name of the objects...Using your first solution gives an error that cannot convert object to gameobject plz help a little more

Comment: @Momin **"As the objects in array are of different lengths so the object are being instantiated on each other but the height do increases**" I now fully understand the problem. Fixed the problem. Use the first code in my answer. I tested it and it works. If your problem is solved, don't forget to accept the answer. Also, I fixed some other problems. When using array, don't hardcode it. It shouldn't be `Random.Range (0, 3)]`. It should be `Random.Range(0, RedgeSets.Length)]`.

Comment: thanks for replying again fortunately i got another solution before your reply but this will also work and i will use it...will accept as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you need a `LinkedList<GameObject>`.

I don't really understand what do you want to check, but whatever, maybe you will figure the whole thing out after I talk about how linked lists work.

Firstly, you should replace your array with a linked list:

```
public LinkedList<GameObject> RedgeSets = new LinkedList<GameObject>();
```

When you want to instantiate a new thing, call `AddLast`:

```
RedgeSets.AddLast(...);
```

You can access the last thing you instantiated like this:

```
LastRedgeSet = RedgeSets.Last.Value;
```

Learn more about linked lists [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx).

I don't really understand what do you want to check for. Maybe you want to execute some code whenever a new thing is instantiated? Then you should maybe look into *events* [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: thanks for your suggestion...fortunately i found anotther way that works perfect with little changes in my code

Answer (score 0):

There is another way,
 1) you can use Multidimensional array A[i][j],i= stores All object & j- stores all by 0 when we storing Object in Array A[i][j].
when you instantiate object then ,at that index of array A[i][j],change value of j 0 to 1.

2) another way is check if( abj==null)
{ not instanciated}
else
{instanciated }
It may work.If it works reply on this answer.

Comment: thanks for answering..fortunately i found  another way that is working perfect with little changes